# calling javascript function for ajax.actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, actionlink

I have the following ajax.actionlink. i want to add click event to this actionlink. How can i do that

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("text", "textaction", new { param = 1}, new AjaxOptions
                            {                                   
                                OnSuccess = "updatePlaceholder",                                
                                UpdateTargetId = "result"
                            })%>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The click event handler is already added to this link because you are using the `Ajax.ActionLink` helper method. This click event handler will cancel the default action and send an AJAX request to the address this link is pointing to. You may try setting the [OnBegin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onbegin.aspx) option.

And if you use jquery in your project you could have a *normal* link (without all the javascript added to your markup by the `Ajax.ActionLink` helper):

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "text", 
    "textaction",
    new { param = 1 },
    new { id = "mylink" })
%>
```

and then in a separate javascript file attach the click event handler:

```
$(function() {
    $('#mylink').click(function() {
        // here you could execute some custom code
        // before sending the AJAX request
        $('#result').load(this.href, function() {
            // success function
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

This way will achieve a clear separation between your markup and javascript files. As javascript will be in separate files which will be cached by client browser you will reduce bandwidth.

Comment: If you are interested, I've got a full example on how wire the  click event of the link with jQuery (as Darin is suggested) in my blog: http://hectorcorrea.com/Blog/AJAX-calls-with-jQuery-in-ASP.NET-MVC.aspx

Comment: The above mentioned solution of ActionLink + jQuery is not working with me. It always navigate to the page and jQuery doesn't handle it properly. Any guess?

Comment: @Zohaib, in my original answer I forgot to cancel the default action of the link by returning false from the click callback. I've updated it to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the code:

$('#mylink').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ....do what ever you want